# Xcode showing unwanted syntax errors

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an enumeration with values:

```
enum Types {
  case A
  case B
  case C
  case D
}

var tableViewDataSource: [Types] = [.A, .B, .C, .D]
```

I want to implement the following conditions:

```
let pickerSelectingFields: [Types] = [.A, .B, .C, .D]
    let indexes = pickerSelectingFields.map { tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }

    if indexes.contains(textField.tag) {
    // Working
    }
```

When I try to make the whole things in a single line, as below it shows error:

> Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Code is below:

```
if ([.A, .B, .C, .D] as? [Types]).map { tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }
                                 .contains(textField.tag)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: let indexes = pickerSelectingFields.map({ tag in tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: tag) }).contains(textField.tag)

Comment: You existing code is not working as far as I see, `indexes` will always contain `0,1,...` and so on depending on how many items you have in `tableViewDataSource` but not on what items you have so `[.A,.B]` and `[.B,.C]` will both return the same result

Comment: want to ask everybody is it a good practice to start the value names with a capital latter?

Comment: Common Swift convention is to start the value names with a lowercase letter, so `enum Types { case a, b, c, d }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([.A, .B, .C, .D] as? [Types]).map { tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }
                             .contains(textField.tag)
```

> What am I doing wrong here?

There are two issues.

First, you used `as?` instead of `as`.  When you use the conditional cast `as?`, the result is `[Types]?`: an *optional* `[Types]`.  Then Swift uses the *optional* version of `map` and you're majorly headed off in the wrong direction.

You needed to use `as [Types]` because you are simply telling Swift to interpret `[.A, .B, .C, .D]` as `[Types]`.

The second issue is that since you're doing this in a single line, you need some extra parentheses `(`, `)` around the closure for `map` because Swift doesn't like multiple `{` after an `if`. Without clarifying parens, it will interpret the first `{` which belongs to the closure for `map` as the start of *then* block for the `if`.

So:

```
if ([.A, .B, .C, .D] as [Types]).map({ tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }).contains(textField.tag) {
    // do something
}
```

will work.

You can also just explicitly type one of the entries of the array, and Swift will interpret the entire array to be `[Types]` like so:

```
if [Types.A, .B, .C, .D].map({ tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }).contains(textField.tag) {
    // do something
}
```

---

**Note:**

It is common Swift convention to start `class`, `struct`, and `enum` type names with *uppercase* letters, and to start variables, methods, and enum values with *lowercase* letters.

So your `enum` could be written as:

```
enum Types {
    case a, b, c, d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make the enum implement `CaseIterable`

```
enum Types: CaseIterable {
  case A 
  case B 
  case C 
  case D 
}
```

Then you can check for the presence of the tag in the array like this

```
if textField.tag >= 0 && textField.tag < Types.allCases.count { //maybe not needed
    if tableViewDataSource.contains(Types.allCases[textField.tag]) {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

Another option is to make the enum of type Int

```
enum Types: Int{
  case A = 1
  case B 
  case C 
  case D 
}
```

And then check directly using the tag

```
if let type = Types(rawValue: textField.tag) {
    if tableViewDataSource.contains(type) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in second line is implicit type which Swift complier can not determine. In short doing `([.A, .B, .C, .D] as? [Types])` does nothing good, you need to be explicit in every type: `([Types.A, Types.B, Types.C, Types.D])`. Now Swift compiler can interpret this as `[Types]`.

You don't need it in the first example because you used explicit type:

```
let pickerSelectingFields: [Types] = [.A, .B, .C, .D]
```

But you would get the same issue by doing it implicitly:

```
let pickerSelectingFields: = [.A, .B, .C, .D]
```

And you could again fix it by giving a hint to compiler:

```
let pickerSelectingFields: = [Types.A, Types.B, Types.C, Types.D]
```

It might be a bit hard to explain/understand but I hope this clears a few things.

Also a bracket is missing so the final result should be:

```
if (([Types.A, Types.B, Types.C, Types.D]).map { tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }).contains(textField.tag) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

This error occurs because you cannot use trailing block syntax in the condition of an if statement. When the compiler sees the opening brace `{`, it assumes it has found the block to be executed when the `if` condition is true. `$0` makes no sense in that context.

To fix it, you must use the non trailing block syntax i.e. put the parentheses for the `map` function call in.

```
if ([.A, .B, .C, .D] as? [Types]).map ({ tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0)}).contains(textField.tag)
//                                    ^- here                                   ^-- and here                            
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

That will leave you with this error:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

That's because of the `as?`. By putting the question mark there, you tell the compiler you are not sure that the array can be converted to an array of `Types` and it therefore assumes it does not have enough information to infer the type. Take out the question mark and the compiler knows it has to be an array of `Types` and can therefore infer the type of the expression correctly.

In fact, if you only have one enum with those members, you might find you don't need the cast:

```
if [.A, .B, .C, .D].map ({ tableViewDataSource.firstIndex(of: $0) }).contains(1)
{
    // do something
}
```

compiles and runs fine in a playground.